# In Laravel how to open webcamera and capture image and store it in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In Laravel I know how to upload an image by browsing In our system then by pressing a button the image was stored in the database.
But now what I need is when a button is pressed I want my web camera to open then I want to capture an image when  I press the capture button and store it in the database. Any help is most welcome.

Comment: https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs ......  
https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/228-How-to-Use-a-Webcam-to-take-Pictures-in-PHP-Application.html

Comment: @Niklesh https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/228-How-to-Use-a-Webcam-to-take-Pictures-in-PHP-Application.html is normal php implementation but i need it in laravel php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Laravel is used at server side. It does not deal with your hardware. For this you need to take help of javascript. Javascript can interact with your webcam, microphone as well as other device hardware. For your starting point you can refer **[RecordRTC | WebRTC Audio+Video+Screen Recording](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/)** great library.

Try to avoid flash based implementation. Because most of the browsers suppose to remove the support of flash.